# Run automated tests from test plans in the Test hub for on-prem TFS 2015

Tags: automated-tests, tfs-2015

We currently have TFS 2015 Update 3, and the web Test Hub seems very limited, especially when it comes to automated tests. You cannot run automated tests from it. I found this article, which seems to be very handy: [Run automated tests from test plans in the Test hub](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub), but it's only available in VSTS. Will this become available to on-prem TFS any time soon?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several **Automated Testing** features planning in future release according to the [features-timeline](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/news/features-timeline), but the feature **Run automated tests from test plans in the Test hub** for TFS on-premise isn't mentioned.

As a workaround, you can link test cases to test methods with MTM or Visual Studio.Then run the test in Test Hub, and switch to **Runs** tab to view test results or run details.

Reference:

- [Automate a test case in Microsoft Test Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Track automated test results with Microsoft Test Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282443.aspx#Track%20automated%20test%20results%20with%20Microsoft%20Test%20Manager)

Besides, you can also execute Automated tests in Build vNext using Test Plan, Test Suites with **Run Functional Tests** task, please refer to below link for details.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/31/executing-automated-tests-in-build-vnext-using-test-plan-test-suites/

Comment: Thanks for the link! Yes we do have them set up to run via Release Management, and for now I'm using MTM to view historical test results. It sounds like MTM is no longer recommended for automated testing activities, so it'd be nice if all features will be made available via the web portal.